# Unable to locate package language-pack-en

Tags: ubuntu, docker, debian, locale, apt-get

On my NodeJS server (running as docker image)...

*Dockerfile*

```
FROM node:4.8-slim
RUN apt-get update -y && \
    apt-get install -yqq locales git
```

...there is no english locale installed:

```
RUN locale -a
```

*gives me*

```
C
C.UTF-8
POSIX
```

In my dockerfile I try to add the missing language

```
RUN apt-get install -y language-pack-en
```

But this gives me

```
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
E: Unable to locate package language-pack-en
```

So how can I add the missing language pack?

---

**Update**

Using

```
sudo locale-gen en_US
sudo locale-gen en_US.UTF-8
sudo update-locale
```

gives me this error:

```
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = "en_US:en",
    LC_ALL = "en_US.UTF-8",
    LANG = "en_US.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_COLLATE to
```

default locale: No such file or directory

Answer (score 52, accepted):

If it's a debian image, you can add the following in your Dockerfile

```
RUN apt-get install -y locales locales-all
ENV LC_ALL en_US.UTF-8
ENV LANG en_US.UTF-8
ENV LANGUAGE en_US.UTF-8
```

Answer (score 7):

try:

```
export LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
export LC_TYPE=en_US.UTF-8
sudo locale-gen
sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales
```

Answer (score 3):

Normally you can install other locales with:

```
sudo locale-gen en_US
sudo locale-gen en_US.UTF-8
sudo update-locale
```

then you can change the values in `/etc/default/locale`.

Comment: Updated the post. Please have a look.